# Injective morphisms between preprojective representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers, preprojective-algebra

Let $Q$ be an acyclic quiver. Is it true that if $P$ is a preprojective representation of $Q$ and $r\geq 0$, there exists $s\geq r$ and a preprojective $P'$ with an injective morphism
$$
P\rightarrow \tau^{-s}P'
$$
where $\tau^-,\tau$ are the Auslander-Reiten translates?

In wild type, it follows frop Proposition 5.3 in
[this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Uz2dAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=irreducible%20map%20between%20pre%20projective%20injective&source=bl&ots=520q2RhOrS&sig=ACfU3U0DNQxqw8R--nSP40XrCHuFGmWh6Q&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU5q-zjvLlAhVLVhoKHVzgCz4Q6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=irreducible%20map%20between%20pre%20projective%20injective&f=false), and in type $A_n^{(1)}$, it follows from [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c974/1742c96cfef7401b05580d3df86dc5d24fb6.pdf), Corollary 2.2.

I am not able to prove it for other affine quivers.

Comment: Maybe a related question is the following one (it implies the previous one): Let $P$ be an indecomposable preprojective. Is there an injective morphism to some other indecomposable preprojective $P'$ ($P'$ not isomorphic to $P$) ?

Comment: In fact, my first question is an easy consequence of Auslander-Reiten theory.